# ansi system and emulation

Tags: ansi, emulation

I have more than just one question here. 
I have been hearing of terms like ANSI server and ANSI server emulation software. I was wondering: 
1. Is there something called **ANSI server**? or what is **ANSI terminal**?
2. Is it possible to emulate one **ANSI server**? if so, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of OT here, but an ANSI terminal is one that handles the [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). There is no such thing as an ANSI Server.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: do you mean that any system could work as ANSI terminal as long as it handled the escape sequences?

Comment: @Neeraj Sure - I've written ANSI terminal simulators for 6502, Z80 and 8086-based systems.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Great! I had actually asked this question because there is a software that needs to run on ansi servers (or ansi terminals). So we needed to have a software that could emulate ANSI terminals on normal, MS-windows based systems. And there is no such software available with us. One of the requirements is to write such a software. I hope I am making sense so far. How long it might take to develop such a piece of emulation software ?

Comment: @Neeraj There is tons of such software available - any terminal emulator will do it, even the Windows command prompt will do it, under the right circumstances.

Comment: @Neeraj: Any reasonable terminal emulator today will support ANSI escapes, including the HyperTerminal bundled with Windows.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, @bobince: thank you, guys. I will do some more search on available software and how windows handles it. Thank you very much.